# sql join no results error in amazon redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

This seems like a simple join in amazon redshift that I have done countless times, but it gives me the following error:

'No results were returned by the query. [SQL State=02000]'

Here is the sql:

```
select   
    campaign_id as product_campaign_id,  
    count(*) as sends  
into table_1  
from customer_to_product_campaign  
group by  
    product_campaign_id  
;  

select  
    product_campaign_id,  
    count(*) as opens_total  
into table_2  
from product_action_oc  
where  
    product_action_type_paid = 'open'  
group by   
    product_campaign_id  
;  

select  
    t1.product_campaign_id,  
    t1.sends,  
    t2.opens_total      
into table_3   
from table_1 t1  
left join table_2 t2  
on t1.product_campaign_id = t2.product_campaign_id  

;
```

Additional info:
-table 1 (which is created without error) is ~ 6K rows
-table 2 (which is created without error) is ~ 10K rows
-the tables do have common product_campaign_id's, not that it should matter

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an error, just a friendly Red Shift notification that there are no results being returned to the GUI.  Basically, the `into` statement is absorbing all the results, so nothing is being returned.

Here is an example.  Consider:

```
select *
into dum
from (select 1 as col) t;
```

This returns the same notification.  But the data is there.  Just do:

```
select *
from dum;
```

to see the one row just inserted.

(Note:  I just tested this on Red Shift.)

Comment: You're completely right!  Thank you!  The odd thing is, the client acts as if it's an error (which I don't think it was doing before) and it states that it is an error, 'An error occurred when executing the SQL command: No results were returned by the query. [SQL State=02000]'.  I've done this type of join so many times before and I'm 95% sure it didn't give me that message.  But as you pointed out, it works.  Thanks again.